# Why is there a space leak in my haskell program using `transpose`

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, space-leak

I have a space leak in my Haskell programm, I could pinpoint it to a minimal example as follows. I would expect the following code (albeit not terminating but I don't care) to run in constant memory but it doesn't:

```
head . filter (const False) $ (transpose [[1..]])
```

while `head . filter (const False) $ [1..]` does run in constant memory.

So it must have to do with usage of 'transpose' on infinite lists I guess.
Ignoring the more complicated base library implementation, if we define transpose like `transpose xss = map head xss : transpose (map tail xss)` , why is there a space leak ? My assumption was that the garbage collector could free the memory formerly consumed by `map head xss` in every step of the `filter` function. I guess that the `map tail xss` somehow prevents that ?! anyway, could I add some sort of strictness annotation or similar to `transpose` so that that simple example does run in constant memory?

Comment: A garbage collector isn't a reference counter. It doesn't free memory as soon as humanly possible. It does so when it feels the need to do so, which is usually when its current region is out of memory and it needs more.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I think this comment is too flippant. Compiling `main = print . <code in question>` with `-O2 -rtsopts` and running with `+RTS -M1g` to set the maximum heap size to 1 gig (which surely ought to be enough if the GC can collect something) results in the process dying from allocating too much.

Answer (score 7):

In your program, the list produced by `transpose [[1..]]` using the simplified version of `transpose` looks like this after a few iterations:

```
map head [[1..]]
  : map head (map tail [[1..]]) 
  : map head (map tail (map tail [[1..]])) 
  : map head (map tail (map tail (map tail [[1..]]))) 
  : transpose (map tail (map tail (map tail (map tail [[1..]]))))
```

Since your `filter` function is only forcing the spine of this list, even when those initial values are tossed, you're still growing a infinite chain of nested `map tail` thunks.

In your example, it should be enough to force the spines of the inner lists, since this will resolve the nested `map tail` thunks.

For example, this runs in constant space using the `transpose` from `Data.List` because the `length` call forces the spine of each inner list.  (It doesn't work with your simplified `transpose`, though.  See @Ben's comment on this answer for an explanation why.)

```
main =
  print $ head . filter (\x -> length x < 0) $ transpose [[1..]]
```

For a more explicit solution, the following seems to work fine.  The `forcelist2` function ensures that every `(:)` that's forced in the outer list forces the head element, and the `forcelist` function ensures that the inner lists are forced to the end, where the final `[]` can be resolved.

```
import Data.List

transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' = forcelist2 . transpose

forcelist2 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
forcelist2 (x:xs) = let !y = forcelist x in y : forcelist2 xs
forcelist :: [a] -> [a]
forcelist (x:xs) = let !ys = forcelist xs in x : ys
forcelist [] = []

main = print $ head . filter (const False) . forcelist2 $ transpose' [[1..]]
```

Comment: I think forcing the inner spines doesn't work with the simplified `transpose` because all those `[[1..]]` expressions in your unfolding are references to the *same* lazy value. Forcing the spine of `map head [[1..]]` evaluates it to a list with a known number of elements (one), but the element is a thunk for `head [1..]`, which has an unevaluated reference to `[1..]`. But when you force the spine of the second list, we end up needing to force `tail [1..]`, which forces that `[1..]` thunk to be unrolled to something like `1 : [2..]`, so that `tail` can drop the `1`. (1/2)

Comment: Forcing the spine of the third list requires forcing `tail (tail [1..])`, which expands the `[[1..]]` to `1 : 2 : [3..]`, and so on. But the original inner list is still holding onto a reference to the *entire* infinite list `[1..]`, and all the `[1..]` are shared references to a single value. So its head elements aren't able to be garbage collected as the various `tail` calls skip over them, and that `head [1..]` thunk is a live reference to an infinite list that is actually being unrolled into memory. (2/2)